# Least upper bound of a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given, e.g., the sequence whose general term is defined by

$$x_n = \frac{3n^2-4}{2n^2-n}$$

it is easy to find a lower bound and an upper bound: $-1<x<3$. I'm wondering how one can find the least upper bound for this sequence.

Comment: Consider the continuous version, $f(x)=\frac {3x^2-4}{2x^2-x}$ on $[1, \infty]$.  It increases to an absolute max and decreases thereafter. Just need to look at the two integers nearest the absolute max.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(x)= \frac{3x^2- 4}{2x^2- x}$ so $f'= \frac{6x(2x^2- x)- 4x(3x^2- 4)}{2x^2- x)^2}=$$ \frac{12x^3- 6x^2- 12x^+ 16x}{4x^4-4x^3+ x^2}=$$ -\frac{6x^2- 16x}{4x^4- 4x^2+ x^2}=$$ -\frac{6x- 16}{4x^3- 4x+ 1}= 0$ when 6x= 16, x= 16/6= 8/3.  What is f(8/3)?